# Microsoft Graph API: Querying calendar events using a custom ID or Field

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have an event driven system where on receiving a certain event I create a calendar event using the Graph API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0

The event contains a `FlowID` which I am using as the [`transactionId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) field in the request payload. Now when I get another type of event with the same `FlowID` I want to delete the event created earlier.

And since I am not really persisting the `ID` of the created event earlier, is there any way to delete the event using the `transactionId` or pull the event using the transactionId and then delete it? Or any other custom field that I can set for that matter? Looking for a solution where I don't have to save the event `ID` returned in the response